# PHP DateTime->format incorrect year

Tags: php, datetime

When using php DateTime object to get date of the last day of the month, the year is always incorrect.

My code is:

```
$d = new DateTime();
$d->modify('last day of this month');
$formattedDateTime = $d->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')
```

Everything is correct apart from the year which is being returned as 7168 instead of 2012.

Anyone any ideas as to what is causing this?

Comment: Works for me: http://codepad.viper-7.com/9ptkPJ

Comment: Works for me too. how did you test it?

Comment: Are you sure your system time is correct? ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have said, it works for me also (PHP 5.4.3).  There have been some bugs in the date/time code over some of the more recent PHP versions, though, so try upgrading your installation if possible and see if that helps.

That being said, you should just be passing the string directly to the constructor instead of using `DateTime::modify()`:

```
$d = new DateTime('last day of this month');
$formattedDateTime = $d->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be related to your version of PHP.

I saw this as the last comment on the [PHP DateTime Relative Formats page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php)

> It should be noted that apparently some of these strings only work in PHP 5.3 
>   apparently, notably:  "first day of this month" and "last day of this month" for example.  According to information found on another website, the "xxx day of" feature was added in PHP 5.3.

Comment: If "last day of this month" wasn't supported by his PHP version, he would be getting an `Exception` thrown from `DateTime::modify()`.

Comment: Well the page says it returns `FALSE` on  failure.  I've put in gibberish strings to `modify()` with no exception thrown.

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking of the constructor.  If it did return `FALSE`, the script would still have failed on `$d->format('...')` though.

Comment: well it would seem the fist step would be to find out which version of PHP were talking about.